# Need edit command in android edit text in danish language

Tags: android

Am doing a danish project, so when i long press in the edit text box i need the "Edit", "copy", "paste" etc commands in danish. In my phone there is no danish language can be selected.

any help is appreciated.

thanks in advance....
jibysthomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Android build must support each localization for the system menus to appear in the desired language. Yes it is possible to support a language by overriding the system menus but if you use Danish as your default language in the app and the system language is set to Danish the system menus will appear in Danish.

Comment: But in the phone there is no danish language to select

Comment: You can still use the Danish language in your app as the default and specified language for your strings. Its a UTF-8 device and in all probability has the Danish specific characters. You can verify this by visiting Wikipedia's [Danish Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet) page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use Typeface for using Danish language without selecting Danish language from your phone language.

And for long press dialog I think you have to make your custom dialog and use that. **I am not sure but this is my idea.**

Thanks.

Comment: Android vanilla has support for many languages and their glyphs. Even if a language's string resources were stripped its possible the fonts were left alone. Its easy enough to test this by using Google Translate to see if the translated output is in the correct glyphs and not empty square boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I use "Scandinavian keyboard " and when i need it press and hold the input box and change the "input method" to this keyboard

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.inputmethod.norwegian&hl=es

hope it works 4 you

Answer (score 0):

Download a custom locale app from the market and use it to change your phone locale to Danish. In your app, you then need to support localization. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) document on **localization**. It helped me a lot when I was localizing an app. Briefly, you will need to create a "values-da" folder under res, create strings.xml and define the strings you need with your Danish values. Don't forget that you need to have a strings.xml file in your regular "values" folder as well with all the strings defined. This folder represents the default string values, and is useful to fall back on if a string is not found in your "values-da" folder.

Trust me, the whole process is actually a lot easier than it sounds.