# Android: choosing between two languages without "locale"

Tags: android, localization, locale

I'm developing application that can be useful only in my country(Ukraine). In Ukraine people primary speak Ukrainian or Russian. And I need to create something like radioButton to switch between languages.

Until now I only found tutorials that were using "locale", but it will not suit my needs, because location is same (Ukraine) but languages are different.

So let's imagine that I have saved in database parameter that show language

I created 2 types of res/values (values-ua  & values-rus). I am starting activity what code I need to use to show which resources I need?

Comment: But you can change the locale from ukraine to russian (and vice versa) programmatically depending on users selection

Comment: Why not have the user decide when you 1st run the program. Maybe make a setting to switch.

Comment: @LaithAlnagem , that is what i'm trying to complete

Comment: @207 thnx, i didn't know that, i think that can be the answer. Will that change have any effect on some other applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that you used the wrong country codes. Try values-ru and values-uk. [[source]](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)

Not fully sure what you intend to do, but I would not provide any radio button. Instead, I would rely on android's built in support for localization. In other words, suppose user A has a device with the Ukranian language enabled by the os, the app will automatically use the strings provided in the strings.xml file which resides in the values-uk folder. Same goes for russian. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407761/need-edit-command-in-android-edit-text-in-danish-language/9408019#9408019) answer- it might help.

Comment: thnx for answer.

 I mean that there can be problem like this: guy who speaks russian and want to use russian interface, will always have ukrainian interface because he lives in ukraine.

Comment: its not about where he lives. the issue is with what language he is using in his device. remember that i can choose to change my device's default language anytime i want. if i can only understand russian, then i would have no choice but to put russian as my default os language (cos i cant read anything else). android will then handle the rest provided your app supports localization.

i don't get the point of the radio button, but you can choose to have it. in that case, merely choose different strings in your java code based on the language.

Comment: forget about radio button :) that was just to show that i want to change language from input and not from some android settings.
Your answer is clear to me and i think i will do as you are saying, but there is a small aspect for example that user prefer to use English as a default language of his phone(just like me). But there will be no English version for my app. And he will get Ukrainian as default, but he is Russian speaker. So maybe there is any way to let user to change language from inside of app? 

great thnx for your time, I apreciate that.

Comment: im afraid you can only choose one default, so your friend has to change his device language to russian in order to read that. you could forget the localization idea if you want, and store your strings as java variables (or inside the same strings.xml file) and use if else statements (or ternary operators) inside the setText. e.g., testTextView.setText(ifRussianSelected ? russianStr : ukranianStr); or something like: testTextView.setText(ifRussianSelected ? R.strings.russianStr : R.strings.ukranianStr); this method is acceptable too but might be a problem as you start adding languages.

Comment: wow, that seems lovely, coz i have only two languages. thnx a lot man you are lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

uk  Ukrainian   ukrainien   Ukrainisch
ru  Russian russe   Russisch

http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php